# Deletion of list elements containing a string character

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering

I have a list:

```
lis = {"ab","a-1","1-20"}
```

from which I need to delete elements of lis that has (only) digits on both sides of the hyphen, in each element that contains a hyphen:

```
res = {"ab","a-1"}
```

Thanks In advance for any advice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DeleteCases`, `Cases`, `Select`, etc. Here a couple of examples:

```
DeleteCases[lis, s_?StringQ /; StringMatchQ[s, DigitCharacter..~~"-"~~DigitCharacter..]]

Select[lis, !StringMatchQ[#, DigitCharacter..~~"-"~~DigitCharacter..]&]
```